# lock block to bottom of scrolled element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a resize grip to my elements. Since the user can resize the elements they have to be able to scroll. The issue I am having is that our requirements state that the resize grip floats beside the scrollbar, even as it scrolls.

I made a jsfiddle that is close to what I need: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7ZxP/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#common-module-inner
{
    height: 200px;
}

#common-module
{
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}

#gs-resize-handle
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="common-module">
    <div id="common-module-inner">
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="gs-resize-handle">
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The red rectangle represents the resize grip. The problem is that when the user scrolls the content the red rectangle stays stationary rather than stay docked at the bottom of the element.

The closest thing I can find to this is docking an element to the bottom of the page, however most of those seem to rely on the window, which is not what I want.

I am not opposed to a jquery based solution, however is it possible to achieve this with html/css?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two changes:

Remove `overflow:auto;` from `#common-module` and add it to `#common-module-inner`

```
#common-module-inner {
    height: 200px;  
    overflow: auto;  
}
#common-module {
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;    
}
```

Here is the demo: Tested in `Chrome & Firefox`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U7ZxP/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing so difficult?

Just take CSS3, and use:

```
resize:both;
```

to your element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7ZxP/10/)

this way you don't need to use jquery or javascript,

remove the red block and just use the handle.

Comment: not exactly what was asked for, but it's simple an clean.

Comment: I don't know why you should take difficult paths, if you can use simple and pure css.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But sometimes there can be problems with browser compatibility or the support of legacy code or plugins. +1 anways.

Comment: @JiFus - Sorry to say but it didn't work for me in both Chrome & Firefox. Please check your fiddle.

Comment: this could be useful someday, however i need to support IE9+

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to position the resize-handle as `fixed` inside the `#common-module` (also fixed), but since this is not possible, I think you need a jQuery-like solution. Since the possibility for resizing is based on javascript (I suppose), you will use Javascript anyway.